# android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE what's the use?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am trying to execute the OnReceive method when Android starts so that I can schedule
a task.

Unfortunately onReceive of my BradcastReciever is called at boot only if I install the app on the
root system. I thought that android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE
should fix the problem.

But from this post it seems that it is not possible, though in certain tutorials
they say it is feasible.

[Android installLocation and BOOT_COMPLETED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391763/android-installlocation-and-boot-completed)

I should infer that I cannot do such a thing.

Is that really so or there is a way to get the broadcast at startup with my app on the sd.

If it is not possible I wonder what's the use
of android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE

This is my Manifest in case someone wnat to take a look.
I am testing on Android 2.3.7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mypackage"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

.............................    

        <receiver
            android:name="mypackage.MyNotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
           >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to split intent filter
Something like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name="mypackage.MyNotificationReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    >
    <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Every filter should have only one action.
Second, a question: ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE occurs always some time after BOOT_COMPLETED (the device first completes boot, then reads card). So why both actions?

Comment: This is incorrect. The docs show one intent-filter can have multiple actions. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers